# A digraph is a graph where every edge is directed. How many digraphs on $n$ vertices are there?

Tags: combinatorics

So far I have that between any two vertices (say $j$ and $k$) there are 3 options.

1. there is no edge between $j$ and $k$
2. there is an edge directed from $j$ to $k$
3. there is an edge directed from $k$ to $j$

And so from this, we can see that there must be $3^{\binom{n}{2}}$ digraphs on $n$ vertices.

I'm not sure if it should be $\binom{n}{2}$ or $\binom{n}{3}$? Can anybody clarify this for me?

Comment: Well, where does the choose part usually come from? Why would it change here?

Comment: It does get more complicated if your definition of a graph assumes that it's (weakly) connected.

Comment: You left out the possibility that there could be an edge from $i$ to $j$ *and* an edge from $j$ to $i$.

Answer (score 2):

In a directed graph, there are $n(n-1)$ distinct edges, each of these can be present or not. Thus the number of digraphs with $n$ vertices should be
$$2^{n(n-1)}$$
Note that this allows two vertices to be connected by directed edges in both ways. This coincides with the definition on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph) (see the example image).

If instead you want to probhibit situations like $v\leftrightarrow v'$ (double-connectedness), you are correct in your enumeration, we pick two vertices in $\binom n2$ ways and assign one of three cases to it independently of the others:
$$3^{\binom n2} = 3^{\frac12 n(n-1)}$$
If the same method was used do allow the fourth case, we would get the original result:
$$4^{\binom n2} = (2^2)^{\frac12 n(n-1)} = 2^{n(n-1)}$$

Answer (score 1):

As ever in combinatorics, you need to be crystal clear about what you're counting, and in particular about equivalence classes.

The OEIS sequence [A000273: Number of directed graphs (or digraphs) with n nodes](http://oeis.org/A000273) counts equivalence classes up to graph isomorphism and appears to exclude graphs with cycles of length 1 (as otherwise there would be two graphs on one vertex).

From your description you seem to be counting digraphs on $n$ *labelled* vertices without cycles of length 1 *or 2*.

So $3^\binom{n}{2}$ could be correct or not depending on what precisely the question is. $3^\binom{n}{3}$ is definitely not correct.